# Animation Shapes in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I use scale animation to scaling the Shapes like Path, Rectangle, ... without memory increasing.
It seems that UWP uses BitmapCache by default in Scale animation and this is because UWP tries to use BitmapCache for smooth animation but I think UWP can clip the BtimapCache to decrease memory usage.

Here is my simple code which builds in Windows10 v1903.

```
 <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="MyStoryboard" >
            <DoubleAnimation To="{Binding MyScale}" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="CompositeTransform"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
            <DoubleAnimation To="{Binding MyScale}" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="CompositeTransform"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"/>
        </Storyboard>

    </Page.Resources>


<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Ellipse x:Name="path"  Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF000000"   Width="200" Height="100"
              >
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="CompositeTransform" ></CompositeTransform>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
 </Grid>
```

and C#:

```
 private void MainPage_OnPointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Properties.MouseWheelDelta > 0)
                MyScale *= 2;
            else
                MyScale /= 2;
            MyStoryboard.Begin();
        }
```

when the user uses the mouse wheel and tries to zoom-in, the memory is increasing.

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my code?

To simplify this question I'm going to compare UWP and WPF in big objects. so I create solutions in both UWP and WPF with just one shape in MainPage. Here are the solutions:

**UWP:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Rectangle Width="20000" Height="20000" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" />
</Page>
```

**WPF:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestScaleBigPath.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowState="Maximized" >
<Rectangle Width="20000" Height="20000" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" />
</Window>
```

WPF only takes 53MB memory while UWP takes 950MB. Here are the Diagnostics Sessions:

**UWP**

[image]

**WPF**

[image]

Comment: I do some search according to this question and I realize that this happen when the size of element is increasing. it's not the problem of animation, it's problem of shape's size.

Comment: When you zoom in an element, the app needs to render the control. The larger the control, the larger the consumption will be, and it will occupy more memory. But if you load a relatively large control at the beginning and handle the zoom size (such as loading a 1000x1000 `Elipse`, but the initial value of `MyScale` is 0.1), there will be no additional memory increase before zooming to the original size.

Comment: yes, you right, but I have worked with the WPF framework, and there is no such problem. I think we have to clip objects into the screen to decrease cache memory.

Comment: Hi, You can try to create a solution in UWP, you can share your thoughts in the answer, this will help more people.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to create solutions in both UWP and WPF and share my thoughts.

Comment: It seems this question doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Hi, UWP and WPF have different rendering mechanisms. During the enlargement process, if the preset size is exceeded, UWP will re-render the element, which will consume system resources. So you can choose to load a large image in advance, and then display it after zooming out. Or control the zoom factor

Comment: Thank you for your comment, It seems that UWP made a big mistake, It can use clipping to decrease memory usage.

Comment: Hi, I am getting in touch with the engineer on this case, and if there is new news, I will post it here

Comment: Hi, After debugging, we found that after scaling, the memory usage will be gradually recovered by the `GC`, thereby falling to a normal level, and will not occupy a lot of memory for a long time. So this is a rendering design, and it's what makes UWP different from WPF. If you still care about this rendering mechanism, you can feedback your problems in the Windows 10 **Feedback Hub**, Thanks